# How to override only one style from Vuetifyjs v.2 in a project using Vuetify v.1.5

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project using Vuetify v1.5. But now, I'd like to use "outlined" css for v-text-field from Vuetify v2 without upgrading the whole Vuetify module. Finding the outlined style in https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify is overwhelming for me. Any suggestion to find the specific style and employ it in my current project?

this style works in my project because of Vuetify v.1.5 (https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields):

```
<v-text-field outline label="name"></v-text-field>
```

this style works in my project because of Vuetify v.2 (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#usage):

```
<v-text-field outlined label="name"></v-text-field>
```

Overriding outline style with outlined is my purpose, but I don't know how to override it because i can't find the specific style of outlined in Vuetify v.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that this is impossible, thanks to the vibrant Vuetify community in (https://discordapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can override or add any style. But you can't do it if your style block marked with scoped.
Try to use full path to selected class, because these framework like bootstrap or vuetify use !important and override it not so easy.
It would be great If you can add some lines of your code